# Submit MVC scaffold form with model nesting association through html select

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I added a scaffold model, project, with CRUD operation, and now I'm trying to adapt it to accept customer model association through user form selection.

```
// model
public class Project
{
    public string Name { get; set; } = "";
    public Customer Customer { get; set; }
}

// controller
using System;
public class ProjectsController : Controller
{
   ...
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Name")] Project project, [Bind("Customer")] long customerId)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // project.Customer = await _context.Customers.FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == customerId);
            _context.Add(project);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
        return View(project);
    }
}

// view
...
<form asp-action="Create">
    <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Name" class="control-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Customer" class="control-label"></label>
        <!-- Easier to read since CustomerItems isn't really a property of the project model but, rendering the list of customers isn't the problem ;) -->
        <select asp-for="Customer" asp-items="Model.CustomerItems">
            <option value="">Choose a customer</option>
        </select>
        <span asp-validation-for="Project.Customer" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
    </div>
</form>
...
```

My problem is at the controller, how can I get the selected customer Id without "infecting" my project model with view logic? I know that I could use the IFormCollection but I think it's overwhelming. In my head it should be something like this:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Name")] Project project, [Bind("Customer)] long customerId)
{
    ...
    project.Customer = await _context.Customers.FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == customerId);
    ...
}
```

I know that I can use ViewModels to encapsulate the objects of the view but then I'd need to replicate the project model validations. I'm attempting to only use (POCOs) models as business rules without ORM references where `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` are accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added an unnecessary bind to customers and named the parameter wrongly.

```
// controller
using System;
public class ProjectsController : Controller
{
   ...
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Name")] Project project, long Customer)
    {
        // FETCH customer manually :(
        ...
    }
}
```

Although I'd like to make it through the project without needing to specify a second parameter to the customer's Id, less code to write like it's done in RubyOnRails.